# Can't resolve issue: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: iptables, linux-kernel, shorewall, ubuntu-12.10

So I am trying to setup shorewall firewall on my linux vps. The vps is running ubuntu 12.10. When I type `$ shorewall` check I get this error.

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
   ERROR: Log level INFO requires LOG Target in your kernel and iptables
```

So I run iptables -L and I get

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I tried looking at other posts and there is one similar, but it did not help me. The kernel I am using is 2.6.32-042stab079.5

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this? I've seen a few things about changing the kernel config, but I have no idea how to do that or what to change.

Comment: You mention VPS. I know of rented virtual machines that simply do not offer iptables-Firewalling inside the VMs.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an OpenVZ based VPS. As with all container-based virtualization, you are limited to the kernel modules provided by the host.

Your options are:

1. Contact the host and request that they make the necessary kernel modules available to you.
2. Use a VPS not based on containers but on full virtualization or paravirtualization, such as Xen, KVM or VMware.

Answer (score 2):

Host on which is hosted your VPS does not provides necessary kernel modules. On CentOS you need to able  to load ipt_LOG.ko if you want to use -j LOG in iptables. You could contact your hoster to clarify this moment

Answer (score -2):

Goto /etc/sysconfig/iptables and add the chain name you are using...
something like this

:FORWARD - [0:0]

Here instead of Forward use you chain name.