# Error with IPTables command

Tags: iptables, fedora-20

I'm trying to run the following command

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables "

And I get the following error:

iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

I'm running Fedora 20 in a vm environment.

Comment: Run the command `virt-what` and post its output. Install it if you don't already have it.

Comment: This question already has an answer here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/532911/cant-resolve-issue-iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name

Comment: Micheal: KVM
Pol:  I did the modprobe with no luck