# IP Rotation using iptables on OpenVZ

Tags: iptables, openvz

I want to set `IP Rotation` using `iptables` so I am using below code.
My server Virtualization Type is `OpenVZ`.
My server provider has enabled all the options then also don't know what is the wrong, It is showing error `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name`.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o venet0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 5 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.1
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o venet0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 5 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.2
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o venet0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 5 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.3
```

They are also ready to enable my needed options so if need any specific option to enable then please tell me.
Or is there any other problem ??? Please help me to solve this.
I found similar question here : [Can't resolve issue: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name](https://serverfault.com/questions/532911/cant-resolve-issue-iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name), but I can find any specific answer there like how to solve it with `OpenVZ`. So, I have created new question for attention.

Comment: @BE77Y, I already checked that post but I dint find any solution. I want to know how to solve this within `openVZ`. My server provider is also ready to enable any needed modules.

Comment: Asking the same question again is still a poor choice in my opinion - if anything you could request that your original question be re-opened.

Comment: @BE77Y, ohk sir. But, please help me to solve this now.

Comment: No - as I've said above, simply duplicating an already-asked question is unlikely to help yourself. In any case, you've found the same response from @c4f4t0r below as on the question linked above - which is almost certainly the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are missing some kernel module in your openvz container, because if I use "`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -o venet0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 5 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.2`" in my linux workstation it works

Maybe the missing modules is `"xt_statistic"`

Comment: Can you tell me which kernel module is needed ???

Comment: try to "modprobe ip_tables"

Comment: They have enabled `IPTABLES="ip_tables iptable_filter iptable_mangle ipt_limit ipt_multiport ipt_tos ipt_TOS ipt_REJECT ipt_TCPMSS ipt_tcpmss ipt_ttl ipt_LOG ipt_length ip_conntrack ip_conntrack_ftp ipt_state iptable_nat ip_nat_ftp "` modules and they have latest kernal.

Comment: lsmod | grep "statistic"
xt_statistic           12601  1

Comment: Your mean i tell my server provider to enable `lsmod | grep "statistic" xt_statistic 12601 1`. right ? is there anything left ??

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, let me talk with my server provider. If it solves my problem then i will mark your post as answer.

Comment: Can i check myself whether `xt_statistic` module is enable or not ??? I have Centos on server.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much... My server provider enabled that option. Now, It is not showing error after those commands. thanks again... ;)

Comment: Need one more favor, how do i check whether ips are being rotated or not.